# Why is choice needed in Ellis' Lemma?

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids, axiom-of-choice, topological-semigroups-and-monoids

Ellis Lemma on idempotent elements asserts that:

> **Lemma (Ellis).** Every compact semigroup has an idempotent.

The proof below is excerpted from Todorcevic's *Introduction to Ramsey Spaces*, [Lemma 2.1](https://books.google.com/books?id=Yhyi8vRfPNAC&pg=PA27).

> Let $S$ be a compact semigroup. Pick by Zorn’s Lemma a minimal compact subsemigroup $R \subseteq S$ and an arbitrary $s \in R$. Then $Rs$ is also a compact subsemigroup and $Rs \subseteq R$. Hence $Rs = R$. Let $P = \{x \in R : xs = s\}$. Then $P \neq \emptyset$, since $s \in Rs$. Note that $P$ is also a compact subsemigroup of $S$. Hence $P = R$ and therefore
> $s^2 = s$.

It appears that Zorn's Lemma is required to obtain a minimal compact subsemigroup $R \subseteq S$. I do not understand why, as it appears to me that we can simply let:
$$
R := \bigcap \{Q \subseteq S : Q \text{ is a compact subsemigroup of $S$}\}
$$
What is the error in reasoning here?

Comment: What if $R=\emptyset$? Note that in Zorn Lemma approach, the nested intersection of non-empty compact sets is non-empty, but without the nestedness you may get the empty set.

Comment: @NickS you're right, thanks! Can you make that an answer?

Comment: A simple counterexample would be the discrete semigroup $\{a,b,ab\}$ where $a,b$ are commuting idempotents. Then $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ are the minimal subsemigroups but the intersection of the two is empty.

Comment: Is it known whether the axiom of choice is necessary for this result?

Comment: @YairHayut according to a comment of [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/94583/146831), the Ultrafilter Lemma is sufficient for Ellis' Lemma.

Comment: So should Todorcevic have written “Pick by Zorn’s lemma a minimal *non-empty* compact subsemigroup”, or is he working with the convention that all semigroups are non-empty?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that $R$ could be empty. When you apply Zorn's lemma, a nested intersection of non-empty compact sets is non-empty, guaranteeing minimal non-empty elements.